# Using FreeRTOS in Atmel Studio 6.2

Tags: atmel-studio, freertos

I have been trying to create an atmel project that uses [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/) on an ATmega328 but I cannot seem to get it to work. I have read several article on how to do this, especially [this](http://www.scienceprog.com/using-freertos-kernel-in-avr-projects/)  and [this one](http://www.scienceprog.com/using-freertos-kernel-in-avr-projects/) (which is in french but google translate should do the trick). Basically, what I did was to:

1. Download the FreeRTOS source code
2. Create a new Atmel Studio (C executable) targeting the atmega328
3. Add the FreeRTOS source code to the project (respecting the folder structure as suggested in the tutorials)
4. Then compile it. However, I get this error "FreeRTOS.h: No such file or directory"
   I have made sure to add all the source file in my compiler's directories (again as suggested by the tutorials) but I always get the same nasty error. Heck, I have even downloaded the attached templates (from the tutorial sites) but I get the same compile error. Does anyone knows how to solve this?
   PS-
5. I am using Atmel studio 6.2 sp2 on windows 8. My compile is the default avr gcc.
6. My directory list looks like this[image]
7. My defined symbols looks like as follows [image]
8. The completed Atmel Studio 6.2 solution is shared to google drive if someone would like to take a look at it
   [Google drive link of the complete solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2M1Y-8quLmkSk5CZTh4UkNyOWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you sure that you have bothe header files : FreeRTOSConfig.h and FreeRTOS.h in the headers directory that you added ?

Comment: Yes! I have all files in place. Nothing is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens if you omit this step from the instructions:

> And in Directories you will need to include all directories containing .h files in your project(I only managed to get working only with absolute paths). Add GCC_MEGA_AVR in Defined Symbols to tell core that we are going to use GCC for AVR microcontroller.

If you think you did that, show us a screenshot of your Directories Settings.

Comment: I have made the requested changes. I added all directories and  added the GCC_MEGA_AVR in Defined Symbols. Yet no changes. Here is the final Atmel Studio Solution File                                 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2M1Y-8quLmkSk5CZTh4UkNyOWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So, now you have "normal" errors. The first is that F_CPU is not defined. Define it with your clock frequency (you may just replace F_CPU with your actual clock frequency). The second error is that a few functions are defined multiple times - This is because you have imported both ATMega323 and ATMega328 includes (port.h, portmacro.h). Remove the ATMega323 files. The third error you made was that you included three different versions of heap_x.c. Remove _2 and _3 files, just leave heap_1 existent. From then on, your project compiles fine.

Comment: I would guess that it compiles. That doesn't mean it works ;-)

Comment: Well! At least I can start testing if it works. I will update my question if it doesn't. But either way, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think I remember having a similar issue in the past...

If you're sure you have everything setup properly, try this: Right-click on the *.h files needed in the project explorer inside the IDE and select properties. You get a little properties window that has a "Build Action" section that is probably set to "none". Click on the drop-down box to change it to "compile". Then rebuild the project.

Hope that solves your problem!

~I'm going to leave this here because it could be useful to someone

Comment: Yes. They are all marked as with a 'compile' option